# Scaling Financial Application with load balancing

Tags: hibernate, architecture, load-balancing, software-design

We have an old financial monolithic application now load on our system got increased and system not able to serve that much load, I'm trying to put my application on load balance (Using Ngnix). From where i need to start?

As the application is a financial application, I am thinking some solutions

1. Run two instance (instance1, instance2) of the application and distribute the load using Nginx.

Problems DB concurrency issue: If i go with this approach both the applications will be connecting to same database and performing operations simultaneously which may cause data inconsistency issue.

2. Develop a mechanism to route all the request in which we are doing any kind of db modification to a fix instance let say instance1.

Can suggest an best approach to solve this problem.

Application should be able to serve the more load and we can put another instance at load balance to distribute load further.

Comment: Also, do you have clarity on where the bottleneck is? Is it the DB or is the web app? Sometimes the code is written in such a way that it just doesn't scale well. I'd go with pezetem solution, share the DB with lock access, and I'd push for a rewrite of the whole app, with a more de-coupled architecture, in parallel. This is an interesting problem. Can I inquire why are you asking this? A bit of the background?

Comment: We have a financial monolithic application we want to put it on load balancing, but because code written in such a way that we can't run two instance pointing to same db.

Comment: All right, look into DB duplication. But, are you 100% sure that the database is the problem? I feel it is far more likely that the code is the problem.

Comment: Also, sometimes databses have poor performance, bceause queries are badly written, and no amount of duplication is going to save you from that. In short, you need to audit your system to come up with a workable solution

Comment: I totally agree with you definitely code is the bottleneck. I was looking some solution if available to overcome this problem.

Comment: Insist on re-coding. Now, you can run as many isolated instances as you want, so first, let's look at your users: Do they all need to share data? Otherwise you can group them into instances, like game shards. If they do, I can only think of coding an additional sync service, to keep all the instances current. Not optimal, extra work, but if you can't reprogram the app, could be a solution.